# Purchasing that extra $5000 in Series I bonds?

Tags: united-states, savings-bonds

According to https://www.treasurydirect.gov/indiv/research/indepth/ibonds/res_ibonds_ibuy.htm#myself I can buy "up to $5,000 in paper I bonds using your federal income tax refund".

But I won't get anything near a $5000 refund.  Heck, I might even owe some money...

What to do?

My crazy idea is to make a $5000 "estimated" tax payment in December, and then get (approximately) that money back in a paper Series I bond.

Is there a better way?

EDIT: yes, I already purchased the online $10,000 this year.

Comment: You can make 'estimated tax payments' at _any_ time, for example _two day_ before you file your taxes... the quarterly IRS dates are only relevant if you _must_ make payments to avoid underpayment-penalties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there's no better way. You can buy up to $10000 from TreasuryDirect, but for that extra $5000 you can get through refund you'd need to first ensure that you're getting a refund. I.e.: yes, you'll need to give the government an extra free loan for a short while to be allowed to give the government a loan that pays interest.